# Reshape json values to value content

Tags: json, jq

I'm not sure if this is even possible with jq but would be very happy if.

The data I receive must be transformed to build parameters for tools I use.

One tool requires the following string as parameter (*it's not a json or json object - simple string*):

`-parameter="{<IP>,[<NAME>,<ALIAS>],<COMMENT>}"`

The source data I recieve is json and looks like this

```
    {
      "MAINSERVER": {
        "COMMENT": "Server",
        "IP": "1.1.1.1",
        "NAME": "Server1",
        "VERSION": "19.4"
      },
      "DATASERVER": [
        {
          "ALIAS": "alias02",
          "IP": "1.1.1.2",
          "NAME": "server02"
        },
        {
          "ALIAS": "alias03",
          "IP": "1.1.1.3",
          "NAME": "server03"
        }
      ]
    }
```

I would like to transform each object array in DATASERVER to a string and push it to the key parameter.

```
{
  "parameter": [
    "{1.1.1.2,[server02,alias02],staticComment}",
    "{1.1.1.3,[server03,alias03],staticComment}"
  ]
}
```

Any support would be really appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible using JQuery only, but are you able to run the query and transform the result in JavaScript or whatever language you are using afterwards?

Comment: I would like to avoid adding code, since it would prevent the possibility to maintain the query for others in the db I'm using. But yes, my last resort would be the manipualation of the data in the code and for that I already have a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Producing the sample output from the question

```sh
{parameter: .DATASERVER | map("{\(.IP),[\(.NAME),\(.ALIAS)],staticComment}")}
```

```json
{
  "parameter": [
    "{1.1.1.2,[server02,alias02],staticComment}",
    "{1.1.1.3,[server03,alias03],staticComment}"
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/YBEEMzva_0)

---

Producing the output from your own solution in a simpler way

```
{parameter: [.DATASERVER | map("{\(.NAME),[\(.IP),\(.ALIAS)]}")]}
```

```json
{
  "parameter": [
    [
      "{server02,[1.1.1.2,alias02]}",
      "{server03,[1.1.1.3,alias03]}"
    ]
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/5x8WlHLb4o)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed it on my own. I thought it's more complex.

Here is my query

```
.DATASERVER  | map((\"{\" + .NAME + \",[\"  + .IP + \",\"  + .ALIAS + \"]}\") ) | {parameter: [.] }
```

result

```
{
    "parameter": [
        [
            "{server02,[1.1.1.2,alias02]}",
            "{server03,[1.1.1.3,alias03]}"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the given template, you could write:

```
jq --arg parameter "{<IP>,[<NAME>,<ALIAS>],<COMMENT>}" '
 [.DATASERVER[] as $l
  | $parameter 
  | sub("<IP>"; $l.IP)
  | sub("<NAME>"; $l.NAME) 
  | sub("<ALIAS>"; $l.ALIAS)
  | sub("<COMMENT>"; $l.COMMENT // "staticComment") ]
 | {parameter: .}
'
```